# How is an air handler's fan controlled if its control board doesn't have a G terminal?

Tags: wiring, hvac, thermostat

### Background

I have a 2-stage cooling heat pump unit from Bryant, installed ~2006 (central Florida):

- Condenser model `698BNX048-B`
- Handler model `FE4ANB006`

Shortly after moving in ~5 years ago, our evap coil was freezing over when cooling and the OEM Bryant thermostat was determined to be the issue. The home warranty company covered the cost of getting a new thermostat put in. The original Bryant thermostat (model `SYSTXBBUID01-A`) is a communicating unit. This thermostat was replaced by a basic Honeywell unit, which as I've recently come to learn, doesn't allow for any of the advanced capabilities of the system (e.g., 2-stage cooling).

The thermostat wiring was changed from the original 4-wire communicating-style setup to a "standard wiring" scheme (`R`/`C`/`Y`/`W`/etc.) Ideally I could reinstall an original Bryant thermostat, restoring all its features, but those run ~$800 new (or ~$400 used on eBay); I don't see myself spending that on a 15 year old unit. Instead, I'm looking into other (cheaper) options, hoping I can at least **restore 2-stage cooling at the compressor**, which is currently running 2nd stage around the clock.

"standard wiring" schematics I've seen online align with how our system is wired (again, no longer communicating style). We have 8 wires from both the thermostat and condenser:

- Brown (unused everywhere)
- Green (connected to `G` terminal at thermostat, but unused everywhere else)
- Red (connected to `R` terminals at thermostat, handler and condenser)
- Blue (connected to `C` terminals at thermostat, handler and condenser)
- Orange (connected to `O` terminals at thermostat, handler and condenser)
- White (connected to `W` or `W1` terminals at thermostat, handler and condenser)
- Yellow (connected to `Y` or `Y1` terminals at thermostat, handler and condenser)
- Black (connected to `Y2` terminal at thermostat, but unused everywhere else)

---

#### Air handler board `CEBD430510`

[image: CEBD430510 board]

- Note: no `G` terminal (**what I'm trying to understand**)
- Note: `HUM` terminal is unused

#### Air handler board wiring diagram

[image: CEBD430510 wiring diagram]

#### Condenser board `CEBD430439`

[image: CEBD430439 board]

- Note: `A`, `B`, `C`, `D` terminals are unused

---

As mentioned, 2-stage cooling is not currently supported with our basic Honeywell thermostat. Our condenser board does not have the Black wire connected to a terminal; instead the `Y2` terminal has a jumper wire from `Y1` to `Y2`. Here is our condenser board's current wiring:

[image: CEBD430439 2-stage jumper wire]

- Note: Black wire is not connected to condenser terminal, but has continuity from thermostat's `Y2` terminal

Restating my goal of **restoring 2-stage cooling at the compressor**, I thought this would be as simple as:

1. Purchase and install a new thermostat with 2-stage cooling capability
2. Remove the brown jumper wire between `Y1` and `Y2` at the condenser
3. Connect the floating Black wire to the `Y2` terminal
4. Save money & extend compressor life

---

### Question

For the setup above, **how is the blower fan in the air handler being controlled?** Everything I've read talks about air handler boards having a `G` terminal to control the fan, but my air handler doesn't have a `G` terminal and the green wires from the thermostat and condenser are unused.

My current assumptions are that:

- Since the fan runs in both cooling and heat modes, the handler must know to start the fan when it has a signal from either `Y` or `W` terminals. If that's the case, **how would the fan know to turn on in a 2-stage cooling scenario where Black wire is energized?**
- Any time the Black wire is energized, the Yellow wire must also be energized (controlled via thermostat) -- this would allow the fan to come on. Energizing the `Black` wire has no impact on the air handler, only the condenser/compressor via the `Y2` terminal.

I know what they say about assumptions, so I'm looking for some more informed feedback. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you post photos of the wiring diagram for your air handler?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel .. added wiring diagram from online manual and confirmed it matches the sticker inside the air handler